# Horton works, Java connection refused exception

Tags: java, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I am having a problem with a connection refused error, I am attempting to use Horton works as a Hadoop server for project testing however I am getting the following error:

```
    java.net.ConnectException: Call From PC/192.168.56.1 to          192.168.0.3:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

After looking at the wiki I am able to complete all the steps including Telnet into the server.

The setup is
VM Virtual Box with Horton running on a bridge connection on 192.168.0.3
with my local connection attempting to run the following Java code.

```
    //1. Get the instance of COnfiguration
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    //2. Create an InputStream to read the data from local file
    //3. Get the HDFS instance
    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://192.168.0.3:54310"), configuration);
    //4. Open a OutputStream to write the data, this can be obtained from the FileSytem
    outputStream = hdfs.create(new Path("hdfs://192.168.0.3:54310/user/hadoop/raw/" + dateToday + "//" + timeStamp.getName()),
                            new Progressable() {
                                @Override
                                public void progress() {
                                    System.out.println("....");
                                }
                            });
```

Is there a way to get the Java program to log-in to the Horton server before attempting the connection?

Comment: Hi Matthew , I am facing same issues . Are you able to solve this issue?